# Behavior of overridden attribute vs a method in scala

Tags: scala

Let us define simplest inheritance:

```
class A           {          val base: String = { println("a hello"); "hello" } }
class B extends A { override val base: String = { println("b hi"); "B hello"} }
```

Now let's try it out:

```
scala> new B().base
a hello
b hi
res0: String = B hello
```

So .. many (/most?) of you out there will likely not be surprised by this.  ***I was*** .  It had been my (incorrect ..) assumption that the `B.base` would ***completely*** override `A.base` . Instead we see **both*** methods being invoked : the base method `A.base` then the overriding method `B.base`.

Ok then .. so is it true that in order to avoid this doubling-up behavior that the `val` must be converted to a `def` (method) ?

```
class A           {          def base: String = { println("a hello"); "hello" } }
class B extends A { override def base: String = { println("b hi"); "B hello"} }
```

And now we have the desired behavior:

```
scala> new B().base
b hi
res1: String = B hello
```

Given this situation: *when is overriding `val` useful within the body of a class*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It had been my (incorrect ..) assumption that the B.base would completely override A.base . Instead we see both methods being invoked : the base method A.base then the overriding method B.base.

No, we don't. The `println` calls in both `A.base` and `B.base` happen *in the constructor*, not when you access `base`. This is just what (non-`lazy`) member `val` means: the right-hand side is executed in the constructor and the result (just `"hello"` or `"B hello"` in your case) is stored into a field. Accessing `base` just returns the value of that field.

And superclass constructor is always fully executed before the subclass constructor, there's no way to override it (you *can* override any methods it invokes, but you need to be careful so they don't rely on subclass' state which isn't initialized yet).

```
scala> val b = new B()
a hello
b hi
scala> b.base
res0: String = B hello
```

> when is overriding val useful within the body of a class?

When you want the subclass' `val` to have a different value, of course.

Comment: This answer did not provide any additional information beyond what I had casually observed *before* recalling the `lazy val` construction that provides the desired behavior.   It is in any case a fair interpretation that `base` *is* (in non-`lazy` case)  accessed - during the invocation of the constructor.

Comment: No, it isn't accessed, it's only initialized. To access it, try adding `println(base)` in `A`'s constructor after `val base`: you'll see that it accesses yet uninitialized `B.base`, precisely because it does completely override `A.base`. The misunderstanding in your question is that `println` is part of the method `base`, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

***LAZY val***

It came to me ..

```
class A           {          lazy val base: String = { println("a hello"); "hello" } }
class B extends A { override lazy val base: String = { println("b hi"); "B hello"} }
```

And now we get expected behavior:

```
scala> new B().base
b hi
res1: String = B hello
```